# Unable to retrieve data from combobox. 

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I am trying to display the result from an if statment which is based upon the option selected within a windows form combo box.
I am having issues when the if statment is placed within its own class seperate to the form and is always just returning the else value. I have made the combobox public.
My code is as follows.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xRayData xRayData1 = new xRayData();
    string shiftChangeValue;
    shiftChangeValue = xRayData1.shiftChange();
    label2.Text = shiftChangeValue;
}

public string shiftChange()
{
    frmSWChange frmSWChange1 = new frmSWChange();

    string shiftLetter;

    if (frmSWChange1.cbShift.Text == "Day")
    {
        shiftLetter = "D";
    }
    else if (frmSWChange1.cbShift.Text == "Night")
    {
        shiftLetter = "N";
    }
    else if (frmSWChange1.cbShift.Text == "Morning")
    {
        shiftLetter = "M";
    }
    else
    {
        shiftLetter = "ERROR";
    }


    return shiftLetter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Selected...` for getting the selected item in combobox

```
frmSWChange1.cbShift.SelectedItem // gets the binded item
frmSWChange1.cbShift.SelectedText // gets the display text of the selected item
frmSWChange1.cbShift.SelectedValue // gets the value of the selected item
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, however once I change the values to .SelectedText I am still always returning the ERROR value

Comment: Can you debug and take a look what stored in the `SelectedText`? Maybe your strings are different.

Comment: Where do you actually do the ShowDialog() of the Form "frmSWChange1"?
In the Constructor of frmSWChange?
It would be nice to design the "frmSWChange" Form in a way that it contains a public property with the selected value. It would help for debugging, reusing the form and uncoupling --> makes your live easier.

Comment: I tried a bit of debugging there and turns out no values are being carried across to the second class.
I tried assigning the value being selected in the combobox to a public static string however I am having the same issue of only Error being displayed.

Comment: And what is stored in your static string?

Comment: Is your `frmSWChange1` is dialog? I just wanted to put some sample how to best organize it

Comment: Ill add how my classes are currently laid out in another answer if thats any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line in your method

```
frmSWChange frmSWChange1 = new frmSWChange();
```

you are creating a new instance of the form and this one has nothing to do with the selection you have made, this will not have any Text selected in the combobox. What you need is the reference to the current instance of the form wherein these selections are being made.

Answer (score 0):

frmSWChange.cs

```
namespace X_Ray
{
public partial class frmSWChange : Form
{

    public frmSWChange()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       frmSWChange1
    }

    private void btnReturnToMainMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new frmMainMenu().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string shiftChangeValue;
        label1.Text = mtxtScrapDate.Text;
        derpderp1 = cbShift.SelectedText;
        xRayData xRayData1 = new xRayData();

        shiftChangeValue = xRayData1.shiftChange();
        label2.Text = shiftChangeValue;
    }

}
}
```

xRayData.cs

```
namespace X_Ray
{
class xRayData
{
    #region Methods


    public string shiftChange()
    {
        frmSWChange frmSWChange1 = new frmSWChange();

        string shiftLetter;

        if (frmSWChange1.cbShift.SelectedText == "Day")
        {
            shiftLetter = "D";
        }
        else if (frmSWChange1.cbShift.SelectedText == "Night")
        {
            shiftLetter = "N";
        }
        else if (frmSWChange1.cbShift.SelectedText == "Morning")
        {
            shiftLetter = "M";
        }
        else
        {
            shiftLetter = "ERROR";
        }


        return shiftLetter;
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for posting an answer :)  Just so you know, put the spaces indentation on *all* lines to make sure the code forms one block.  However, its sometimes a good idea to break it up, but if so, put in some explanation.  There should always be some explanation at the top.  If you edit it with a lil' explanation it'll get some upvotes ;)